# Does Android account manager encrypts information stored in it?

Tags: android, security, accountmanager

My requirement is to store username and password in my application.
I am storing username and password using [android accountmanager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) and I am not able to get any straight answers to following queries:

1. Do i need to encrypt credentials before storing them in
   accountmanager?
2. Does android account manager uses any encryption machenism by default?
3. How secure are credentials while stored in account manager against rooting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No, you need to use Cipher class to encrypt
3. If you are root, you can access data easily and get the key for encrypt data. The best is to store the key in some native lib, more difficult to disassemble native lib.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. So there is really no security against rooting in accountmanager?